# Python create a data structure of "list with sublists" with unkown number of elements in the list and sublist

Tags: python, list

I am looping through some data from which I want to pull an unknown number of elements, each of them has an unknown number of sub-elements. I want to save this all in a data structure that is formatted somewhat like this.

```
data_structure = [x_1 [x_1_1 , x_1_2,  ... x_1_n] , x_2 [x_2_1 , x_2_2,  ...x_2_m] ... x_j [x_j_1 , x_j_2,  ...x_j_k]]
```

the indexes n,m,j,k are all of varying length. The elements and sub-elements are strings.

Is there a way to do this without having to know the size of the list and each of the sublists in advance? I tried just using a list and assigning them like data_structure[index][index] but that is not possible since those indices are obviously not present.

Edit:
My data is an xml document that I parse with xml.etree.ElementTree

the code that is relevant for this is:

```
def playlist_creation(rb_tree_root,tra_tree,traktor_tree_root): 
    for element in rb_tree_root: #rb_tree_root is the root of the xml element tree
        if element.tag == "PLAYLISTS":
            print('in playlists')
            for folder_parent_node in element:
                # in <NODE Type="0" Name="ROOT" Count="2"> of rb xml
                #print('Node attribute : ',folder_parent_node.attrib['Name'])
                playlist_list = []
                index = 0
                for folder_child_node in folder_parent_node:
                    # in <NODE Name="Hochzeit" Type="0" Count="12"> for first iteration
                    folder_name = folder_child_node.attrib['Name']
                    playlist_list[index] = folder_name
                    for playlist_node in folder_child_node:
                        # in <NODE Name="Classic Pop" Type="1" KeyType="0" Entries="16"> for first iteration
                        playlist_names.append(playlist_node.attrib['Name'])
                    playlist_list[index][index] = playlist_names
                    index += 1
```

Error message is:
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

the xml looks like this and I want to pull the playlist folder names and names of the individual playlists from the xml and save them in a data structure.

here is a cut down version of the xml

```
<DJ_PLAYLISTS Version="1.0.0">
  <PRODUCT Name="rekordbox" Version="5.6.0" Company="Pioneer DJ"/>
  <COLLECTION Entries="3566">
    <PLAYLISTS>
    <NODE Type="0" Name="ROOT" Count="2">
      <NODE Name="Hochzeit" Type="0" Count="12">
          <NODE Name="Classic Pop" Type="1" KeyType="0" Entries="16">

      </NODE>
        <NODE Name="Elektro" Type="0" Count="15">
      </NODE>
    </NODE>
  </PLAYLISTS>
</DJ_PLAYLISTS>
```

Comment: so If i understood correctly you want to iterate a data structure - some kind of JSON? - and map to list?

Comment: Maybe you can look at `defaultdict` and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Comment: You don't need to allocate an initial length for a list. You can just append new elements as you find them. It also seems like a dict of lists is more appropriate for this case. Can you show what your input data looks like?

Comment: @Manu its an xml i edited my original post

Comment: @Sandertjuhh I will have a look at it thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @quamrana I thought since this is a very broad problem it would be better to keep it to pseudo code. I edited my post now

Comment: @Reti43 I didnt manage to add my data to specific indices like list[index][index]. Input data excerpt is in my post now